# Can I search Taxonomy terms within display suite

Tags: search, display-suite

I don't think so, but I'm throwing it out just in case I am incorrect

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by search?

You can apply ds layouts to taxonomies

Comment: Search, you can use Display suite as a search mechanism for a site.  But I don't see that you can configure the search on tax terms the way you do on a content type.  Is there an add on aor am I missing a configuration

Comment: I don't understand this feedback. It's my question. I'm answering his comment

Comment: I think he meant that my answer was not really an answer and more like a critique or request clarification, so i should have commented your question instead of answer it.